# Asp.Net Core not receiving token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, identity

I have implemented an identity provider using indentiyserver4 to authenticate my API's. I was wondering if it is possible for the IDP to authenticate **itself**. currently when i send the access_token to my IDP i don't receive any claims.
i would like to add the authentication in order to allow only admins to manage users.

Comment: please view this link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fhfvbl_KbWo&list=PLOeFnOV9YBa7dnrjpOG6lMpcyd7Wn7E8V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client requests an access token for certain scopes only. These scopes are part of resources, making sure the access token can only be used by certain audiences. The reason the IDP ignores the claims, is because the IDP is not part of the resource.

If you want to extend the IDP with Api endpoints, e.g. for Admin like functionality that has to be accessible by clients, then you can configure this like any other api. If the client is allowed to request the scope then the claims will be part of the access token and, being an audience, the IDP will see the claims.

But for Views / Pages on the IDP you can simply use cookies. On login you can add these claims to the local cookie.

In code you can use authorization like normal. You can define policies and use filters and attributes.

---

Suppose a user is part of the 'Admin group' then you can add this role on login to the cookie.

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user.Id, user.UserName, new Claim("role", "Admin"));
```

With the Authorization attribute you can limit access to a controller in the IDP. You can configure a policy:

```
services
    .AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AdminRole", p => p.RequireRole("Admin"));
    });
```

and limit access on controller level:

```
[Authorization("AdminRole")]
```

Use schemes to specify if authorization uses a bearer token.

```
[Authorization("AdminRole", AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `Authorization` on IdentityServer. To have this no need to pass access_token to IDS4, just add `[Authorize]` attribute for the controller/action you need to be authorized.
Good example is [ConsentController](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/samples/Quickstarts/2_InteractiveAspNetCore/src/IdentityServer/Quickstart/Consent/ConsentController.cs#L22) on the quickstart